# If $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{a_n}$, show that the sequence converges and find the limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

If $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{a_n}$, $\forall n\in N$, then the sequence converges, so find its limit.

So I list the elements of the sequence as follows:
$$1, 2, \frac{5}{2}, \frac{13}{5}, \frac{34}{13}, \frac{89}{34},\dots$$

And we see that this a increasing sequence, because $1\lt 2\lt 2.5\lt 2.6\lt 2.61\lt 2.6176$, and we see too that the sequence is bounded, by 1 as an inferior bound, but we want to know its limit, wich we cannot clearly see from the sequence above.

Then, to give an expression:
$$a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}$$

And if we repeat the process of substitution we have:
$$a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{a_{n-2}}}}$$

So, finding the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} 3-\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(3-\frac{1}{a_k})}$$

$$3- \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(3-\frac{1}{a_k})}$$

$$3- \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(3)}$$

$$3- \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{3}= 3-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{8}{3}\approx 2.\overline6 7$$

Is this the right way to handle this? Let me know if I did something wrong or if I was unclear, thank you.

Comment: Hint to find the limit: $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n}$ have the same limit. Consider calling it $L$ and applying the recursion.

Comment: If limit $L$ exists, then $L=3+\frac{1}{L}$. Note that $(a_n)$ is limited, then there is a subsequence convergent.

Comment: $3 - \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (3-\frac{1}{a_k})}$ is simply $3-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{2}-\dots-\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}$ which is completely different from the continued fraction $3-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{3-\dots}}}$

Comment: `a[n] /. (RSolve[{a[n + 1] == 3 - 1/a[n], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n] // FullSimplify)[[1]]`

Mathematica shows the result is $\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right) \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)^n+\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)^n}{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right) \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)^n+2 \left(\sqrt{5}-2\right) \left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)^n}$

Comment: "And we see that this a increasing sequence".... no, we don't see that. We only see that the first 6 elements of the sequence are increasing.

Answer (score 5):

**Here is an approach with analytic solution.**

Let's denote $a_n = x_{n}/ x_{n-1}$ with $x_0 = 1$ and $x_1 = a_1 \cdot x_0 = 1$, then:

$$a_{n+1} = 3-\frac{1}{a_n} \iff\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}= 3 -\frac{x_{n-2}}{x_{n-1}} \iff \color{red}{x_n = 3x_{n-1} -x_{n-2}} \tag{1} $$

The recurrent relation $(1)$ can be solved via the characteristic equation (for example: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm)) :
$$x^2 -3x +1=0 \iff x_{1,2} =\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} \tag{2}$$
$$\implies x_n =p\cdot x_1^n + q\cdot x_2^n \tag{3}$$
As $(x_0,x_1) = (1,1)$ we deduce easily that $$(p,q) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}  \right) \tag{4}$$

And then

$$\color{red}{a_n =\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}} = \frac{p\cdot x_1^n + q\cdot x_2^n}{p\cdot x_1^{n-1} + q\cdot x_2^{n-1}}}$$
with $(x_1,x_2,p,q)$ defined by $(2),(4)$

As $0<x_2<1$, it is easy to prove that
$$ \lim_{n\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\infty}\frac{p\cdot x_1^n + q\cdot x_2^n}{p\cdot x_1^{n-1} + q\cdot x_2^{n-1}} = \frac{p\cdot x_1^n}{p\cdot x_1^{n-1}} = x_1 = \color{red}{\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}$$

Comment: (+1) That's amazing technique to resolve the recurrence relation into linear form... but I guess it's **not** for someone who is having this as a homework for $\text{Analysis-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

first we want to prove that the sequence $a_n$ is monotone then we have to prove that the sequence is bounded (to use monotone convergence theorem  )

> ***Monotone convergence theorem:-*** A monotone sequence of real numbers is
> convergent if and only if it is bounded

since $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$ assume that $a_{k+1 } >a_{k}$ implies $\frac{1}{a_k}-\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}>0$ then $a_{k+2 } - a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{a_k} - \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} >0$ so that mean if $a_{k+1 } >a_{k} $ then $a_{k+2}> a_{k+1}$ which imply that $a_{k+3}> a_{k+2}$ which imply that $a_{k+4}> a_{k+3}$ notice something ? this means that the sequence is strictly increasing (by [Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)).

assume $0<a_{k-1} < 3$ then $a_k = 3-\frac{1}{a_{k-1}} < 3$ (since $a_{k-1} >0$) then it is bounded above by $3$ ($3$ is just an upper bound and not the least upper bound which is the limit of the sequence  )

then by Monotone convergence theorem the limit of the sequence $a:= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty }a_n$ exist, so $a= 3- \frac{1}{a}$  $a^2-3a+1 =0 |a>1$ then $a=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} $

Comment: I would suggest that you mention that you have used induction for otherwise it's often hard for beginners to catch on... :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $a_{n+1}$ is equal to some real number $L$. Then the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $a_n$ is also $L$, so we have $L=3-\frac{1}{L}$. Multiplying through by $L$ and shifting everything to the left yields $L^2-3L+1=0$. Solving for $L$, we get $L=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so $L=2.618$ (to $3$ decimal places) or $L=0.381$ (to $3$ decimal places). You have already determined that the sequence is increasing, and since $0.381\lt 1$, $L$ must be $2.618$. Funnily enough, this is also equal to $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$, where $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the constant known as the golden ratio!

Comment: Amazing! thank you

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Comment: @H.sapiensrex "Funnily enough", for all $k\in\mathbb N$, the roots of the equation $x^2-(F_{2k-1}+F_{2k+1})x+1=0$ are $\varphi^{\pm 2k}$.  (where $F_i$ is the $i$-th term in the Fibonacci sequence with seeds $F_0=0, \ F_1=1$.)

Answer (score 2):

$~\underline{\text{Outline of Steps}}$

- S1: Show that $~\langle a_n\rangle ~$ is bounded.
- S2: Show that $~\langle a_n\rangle ~$ is strictly increasing. 
  At this point, you can conclude that $~\langle a_n\rangle~$ is convergent, with some unknown limit $~L.~$
- S3: Show that for $~x > 0,~$ that $~f(x) = 3 - \dfrac{1}{x}~$ is a continuous function.
- S4: At this point, you have that for $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ as $~n \to \infty, ~a_n \to L.~$ 
  Since $~f(x)~$ is a continuous function, this implies that as $~n \to \infty, ~f(a_n) \to f(L).$ 
  However, you also have that $~f(a_n) = a_{n+1}.$ 
  So, you can conclude that as $~n \to \infty, ~f(a_n) \to L.$ 
  Therefore, you can solve for $~L = f(L) \implies L = 3 - \frac{1}{L}.~$

---

$~\underline{\text{Actual Work}}$

**S1**:

Note that

$$\frac{\sqrt{5}+3}{2} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5} + 3} = \frac{5 + 9 + 6\sqrt{5} + 4}{2 \times \left[ ~\sqrt{5} + 3 ~\right]} 
= \frac{18 + 6\sqrt{5}}{6 + 2\sqrt{5}} = 3.$$

$\displaystyle a_2 = 2 \implies \frac{3}{2} < a_2 < \frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}.$

Suppose that $~\displaystyle \frac{3}{2} < a_n < \frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}.$

Then

$$\frac{3}{2} < \frac{8}{3} = 3 - \frac{2}{3} < a_{n+1} < 3 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{5} + 3} = 
\frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}.$$

Thus, for all $~\displaystyle n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}, ~\frac{3}{2} < a_n < \frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}.$

---

**S2:**

From the end of section **S1**, you have that for all $~\displaystyle n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}, ~\frac{3}{2} < a_n < \frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}.$

Therefore, $~0 < a_n - \dfrac{3}{2},~$ and

$$\left[ ~a_n - \frac{3}{2} ~\right]^2 < 
\left[ ~\frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2} - \frac{3}{2} ~\right]^2 = \frac{5}{4} \implies $$

$$\left[ ~a_n - \frac{3}{2} ~\right]^2 - \frac{5}{4} < 0 \implies $$

$$(a_n)^2 - 3a_n + 1 < 0 \implies $$

$$(a_n)^2 < 3a_n - 1 \implies $$

$$a_n < 3 - \frac{1}{a_n} = a_{n+1}.$$

Therefore, $~\langle a_n\rangle~$ is a strictly increasing sequence.

Therefore, $~\langle a_n\rangle ~$ converges to some unknown value $~L.$

---

**S3:**

Here, there are a variety of easy approaches.  I am going to take the hardest approach, which involves going *back to basics*, via $~\epsilon,\delta.$

To show, for any $~x_0 > 0:$
$~\forall ~\epsilon > 0, ~\exists \delta > 0,~$ such that

$$|x - x_0| < \delta \tag1 $$

$$\implies \left| ~\left(3 - \frac{1}{x_0}\right) - \left(3 - \frac{1}{x}\right) ~\right| < \epsilon $$

$$\iff \left| ~\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x_0} ~\right| < \epsilon. \tag2 $$

$$\text{Set} ~\delta = \min\left[ ~\frac{\epsilon \times (x_0)^2}{2}, ~\frac{x_0}{10} ~\right]. \tag3 $$

Using (1) above, you have that

$$-\delta < x - x_0 < \delta \implies $$

$$x_0 - \delta < x < x_0 + \delta \implies $$

[since $~x_0 - \delta \geq \dfrac{9x_0}{10} > 0 ~$]

$$\frac{1}{x_0 + \delta} < \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{x_0 - \delta}. \tag4 $$

The constraint in (2) above, which must be satisfied, is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{x_0} - \epsilon < \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{x_0} + \epsilon. \tag5 $$

So, the problem has been reduced to showing that (3) and (4) above collectively imply (5) above.  Comparing (4) and (5) above, it is sufficient to show that (3) above implies that

$$\frac{1}{x_0} - \epsilon < \frac{1}{x_0 + \delta} \tag6 $$

and

$$\frac{1}{x_0 - \delta} < \frac{1}{x_0} + \epsilon. \tag7 $$

(6) above is equivalent to showing that

$$\frac{1}{x_0} - \frac{1}{x_0 + \delta} < \epsilon \iff $$

$$ \frac{\delta}{x_0(x_0 + \delta)} < \epsilon \iff $$

$$\delta < \epsilon(x_0)(x_0 + \delta). \tag8 $$

By (3) above, $~\displaystyle \delta \leq \frac{\epsilon (x_0)^2}{2} < \epsilon (x_0)^2 < \epsilon(x_0)(x_0 + \delta).$

Therefore, the result in (8) is implied, so the result in (6) is also implied.

Similarly, (7) above is equivalent to showing that

$$\frac{1}{x_0 - \delta} - \frac{1}{x_0} < \epsilon \iff $$

$$ \frac{\delta}{(x_0 - \delta)(x_0)} < \epsilon \iff $$

$$\delta < \epsilon(x_0)(x_0 - \delta). \tag9 $$

From (3) above, you have that

$$\epsilon(x_0)(x_0 - \delta) \geq \epsilon \times \frac{9(x_0)^2}{10},$$

so, (3) above implies (9) above, which implies (7) above.

---

**S4:**

$$L = 3 - \frac{1}{L} \implies L^2 - 3L + 1 = 0 \implies $$

$$L = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 3 \pm \sqrt{5} ~\right].$$

Using the bounds established in **S1**, the smaller value above must be rejected.  Therefore,

$$L = \frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with recurrently defined sequences, I assume that you have studied basics of functional analysis already.

Let $f:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$. $$f(x):=3-\frac{1}{x}$$

Redefine your sequence as $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ with the seed $a_1=1$.

You can show that $f$ is a strictly increasing function by taking its derivative which is always positive.

Clearly, $a_1=1,\ a_2=2$. $$a_1<a_2\implies \underbrace{f(a_1)}_{=a_2}<\underbrace{f(a_2)}_{=a_3}$$ because a strictly increasing function, by definition, "preserves" the inequality when applied to both sides.

$$ a_1<a_2\Rightarrow a_2<a_3  \Rightarrow a_3<a_4\Rightarrow  \cdots$$

It follows by induction that $$0<a_1<a_2<a_3<\cdots$$ i.e., $\{a_n\}$ is monotone increasing.

Now we'll show that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above by $3$. For all $n\in\mathbb N$,
$$a_{n}>0\\ \implies \frac{1}{a_n}>0\\ \implies 3-\frac{1}{a_n}<3\\ \implies a_{n+1}<3$$

An alternate way to establish the above would be to use the fact that $\{a_{n}\}\subset f(\mathbb R^+)$ so each $a_n$ is less than the global maxima of $f$ which is given by $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=3$$ because $f$ is increasing.

**Conclusion**: $\{a_n\}$ is a monotone increasing sequence and it is bounded above.

By monotone convergence theorem, $\{a_n\}$ converges and hence, the existence of $\lim a_n$ is guaranteed. $\blacksquare$

---

It's routine to show that :$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c) \text{ for all } c>0$$

Suppose, the non-constant sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to some limit $\ell>0$.

By sequential criterion for limit of a function at a point, $\{f(a_n)\}$ should converge to $f(\ell)$.

$$\because \ \lim_{x\to \ell }f(x)=f(\ell) \\ a_n\to \ell \implies f(a_n)\to f(\ell)$$

Notice that the seq. $\{f(a_n)\}$ is same as $\{a_{n+1}\}$ so it should converge to the same limit as $\{a_n\}$.

Thus, we need that $$\lim f(a_n)=f(\ell)=\ell=\lim a_n$$

Now, solving $f(\ell)=\ell$ yields a quadratic equation with two roots, only one of which meets our requirement that $a_1=1$ and $\{a_n\}$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be approached via the fixed point theorem. Since $g(x) = 3-\frac 1x$ is invariant and contractive in $[1, +\infty)$, the fixed point theorem guarantees that the equation $g(x)=x$ has one and only one solution $\alpha$ in that interval and that the sequence $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ converges to $\alpha$, for any initial approximation $x_0 \ge 1$.

Note: There is a minor inconvenience with the fact that $g'(1)=1$, but we can see why this does not change the convergence of the sequence.

Comment: $|g'(x)|<1$ for all $x\in (1,\infty)$ is a sufficient condition for $x_n$ to converge... Is this the conclusion from "fixed point theorem"? I am asking this cuz I have read about convergence criteria for fixed point iteration method in a numerical analysis course, but never heard of this theorem as such...

Comment: When a function is differentiable, being contractive is the same as having $|g'|<1$. The notion of contractivity is more general and applicable in higher dimensions (also infinite dimension). Also, the $|g'|1$ alone does not ensure convergence. I now realize that I had a typo in my post: When I wrote "continuous" I should have written "invariant".

Answer (score 0):

You guess that x = 3 - 1/x, so $x^2 = 3x - 1$ and $x = 1.5 +- \sqrt {1.25}$. Then you calculate what happens if you start with $x + \epsilon$ to prove convergence.

Answer (score 0):

$3,2,5/2,13/5,...$

$0<3-1/a_n-a_n$

$a_n^2<3a_n-1$

$\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}<a_n<\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\implies a_{n+1}>a_n$

$\forall \epsilon, 0<\epsilon<\sqrt{5}, \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\epsilon<a_n<\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

So $n \to \infty, a_n \to \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ increasing to the limit from the initial value $1$. This is consistent with the monotone convergence theorem.